# MonoGame EffectPass.Apply() doesn't work

Tags: monogame, hlsl

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(effect: effect);

// Draw stuff normally

effect.Parameters["flag"].SetValue(true);
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

// Draw stuff with flag

effect.Parameters["flag"].SetValue(false);
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

// Draw stuff normally
```

But this doesn't work. The flag stays false even after I apply the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe it's because of how SpriteBatch works. the effect is being run when all the sprites are submitted to the gpu. You have to either call spriteBatch.End() or set SpriteSortMode to Immediate or Texture

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to pass the effect to spritebatch begin. You are handling it all yourself.

EDIT: Because you call 
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
You don't need to pass the effect to the Begin function

Comment: I suggest you elaborate your answer.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question